# Find Generic List record based on index

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I m in a situation where i need to find record from a generic list using its position, means need to find 1st 5th and 9th record , then 2nd 6th and 10th record and so on...

Situation is

A list of projects assigned to a List of Team,
So if we have 20 projects and 4 teams

then 1st project go to 1st team, 2nd go to 2nd team , 3rd go to 3rd team, 4th go to 4th team 
then again 5th project go to 1st team

so its like

```
Projects              Team
1                     1
2                     2
3                     3
4                     4
5                     1
6                     2
7                     3
8                     4
9                     1
.
.
```

so now i want to run a Query on Generic List to get record for each team, so for first team record 1,5 and 9.... need to fetch.

Some thing like

```
 List<Project> lst = list (from Database)
 //For 1stTeam 
lst = lst.Index(1,5,9...);

//For 2nsTeam 
lst = lst.Index(2,6,10...);
```

Hope i clear my point.

Comment: question is not so clear!!. can you elaborate it please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, this is not specific to generic lists.

---

You have to create a new list, and then, one by one, add the items from the original list that you want in the new list. You can access single items at a given position via the indexer (square brackets).

```
List<Project> lst = // list (from Database)

List<Project> firstTeam = new List<Project>();
firstTeam.Add(lst[1]);
firstTeam.Add(lst[5]);
firstTeam.Add(lst[9]);

List<Project> secondTeam = new List<Project>();
secondTeam.Add(lst[2]);
secondTeam.Add(lst[6]);
secondTeam.Add(lst[10]);
```

---

Of course, if the items are distributed that regularly throughout the original `lst`, you can automatically determine the items:

```
List<Project> firstTeam = new List<Project>();
for (int i = 1; i < lst.Count; i += 4) {
    firstTeam.Add(lst[i]);
}
```

i.e. you loop over the original list, taking every 4th item.

---

If the items to add to one of the teams are *not* distributed regularly throughout `lst`, you will have to add them one by one, but you might be able to make use of the shorter list initializer syntax:

```
List<Project> firstTeam = new List<Project>() { lst[1], lst[5], lst[9] };
```

---

Lastly, note that `List<T>` starts counting indices at zero, so the very first item is `lst[0]`, not `lst[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this with LINQ `Select` and `GroupBy`:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int numberOfTeams = 4;
var projectsByTeam = list
 .Select((number, index) => new {Value = number, Index = index})
 .GroupBy(item => item.Index % numberOfTeams)
 .Select(item => new {TeamNumber = item.Key+1, ProjectIDs = item.Select(x => x.Value).ToList()})
 .ToList();
```

Splits the original list into

```
{
  {TeamNumber = 1, ProjectIDs = {1,5,9}}, 
  {TeamNumber = 2, ProjectIDs = {2,6,10}}, 
  {TeamNumber = 3, ProjectIDs = {3,7}}, 
  {TeamNumber = 4, ProjectIDs = {4,8}}, 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) keyword. It will allow you to pass in to `Index` an array of arguments, which are the indexes in your case.

In your case an extension method can do the trick:

```
public static List<Project> Index(this List<Project> list, params int[] indexes) 
{
  var newList = new List<Project>();
  foreach(var index in indexes)
  {
     newList.Add(list[index]);
  }
  return newList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
List<Project> projects; // = something from db
var neededIndexes = new[] { 0, 4, 8 };

var result = projects.Where((project, index) => neededIndexes.Contains(index)).ToList();
```

Or if the indexes are evenly distributed:

```
List<Project> projects; // = something from db

var result = projects.Where((project, index) => index % 4 == 0).ToList();
```

Comment: This must be the most obfuscated way of accessing items by index I have seen so far.

Comment: I prefer Linq chaining over for loops when it can be kept in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Define other methods and classes here
static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CustomSplit<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int max)
{
    var results = new List<List<T>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
        results.Add(new List<T>());
    }

    int index = 0;
    using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            int circularIndex = index % max;
            results[circularIndex].Add(enumerator.Current);
            index++;
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

And here is how to use it:

```
void Main()
{
    var elements = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).CustomSplit(4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solve your problem:

List for each team:

```
List<List<Project>> projectsPerTeam = new List<List<Project>> ();
for(int i=0;i<teamsList.Count();i++)
{
    projectsPerTeam.Add(new List<Project> ());
}
```

Now your issue (add project for correct team):

```
for(int i=0;i<projectsList.Count();i++)
{
    projectsPerTeam[i%teamList.Count()].Add(projectsList[i]);
}
```